# Is it possible to synchronize vscode terminal emulator's working directory with an editor's?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'll like to have the terminal automatically change directory to the editor's current directory anytime I switch editor.

I'm used to this in Emacs so I was thinking if it was possible to make VSCode have this same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is supported out of box as of VS Code 1.24. However this could be implemented by an extension (see discussion [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/38566))

Implementing this will likely require this VS Code extension API addition: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/46192

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a simple extension that does just this. Take a look at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maciejdems.terminal-sync.